# How to access a DLL's variable from the calling program?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, unity-game-engine, scope

I have a .dll that I'm trying to get to work with **Unity3D**. What I need is **real time communication** between the two so within the DLL I've got a loop which does some calculations and then calls the following function with arguments myvalue, 0

```
__declspec(dllexport) double __cdecl MyMathFuncs::Divide(double value, double b)
{
    static int numfound = 0;            
    if(value == -1 && b == -1) //for args -1, -1, this is a...
        return numfound;   // ...GETTER
    else numfound = value ;  // if args are other then -1,-1, this is a SETTER
    return -1;
}
```

The problem is that every time this function is called as a getter from Unity's Update() function, it **returns zero**, regardless of what I've set it to in the loop of the other function. I tested it in Visual Studio and I'm getting the expected output there - so I suppose there is an issue with the **scope or the lifetimes** of the variables. I also tried declaring a global variable and accessing it but its value is zero as well. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method does return

- `0` if `value` and `b` equal `-1`
- `-1` otherwise.

Are you sure the last statement shouldn't be `return numfound` (or `return value`)?

Setting `numfound = value` does not have any effect on the output since you reinitialize `numfound` with each methodcall. If you want to use this outside of the method you are right that you need to make this a global variable.

Comment: I need to "save" the value of the integer set by "value" for when the function is called as a getter - I thought a static variable would do the job

Comment: static does not help you here - the point is that you need to declare the variable as member of your class. Currently you declare it inside of a method - thus it will only be available inside of this method.